# Gnuplot with epslatex terminal

Tags: gnuplot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gnuplot subdirectory not found using epstopdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21193/gnuplot-subdirectory-not-found-using-epstopdf)

Hello i have been folowing a procedure to insert a high quality graph into my document using gnuplot 4.6. This is what i did step by step:

1. i created a `sample.gp` file with a source code as follows:

   ```
   set terminal epslatex
   set output 'test.tex'
   f(x) = sin(x)
   plot f(x)
   ```
2. i converted source file using `gnuplot sample.gp` and got 2 files named **test.eps** and **test.tex**.
3. But **.eps** format doesnt suit me as i want to compile a Latex document using PDFLatex. this is why i used ghostscript command `ps2pdf13 -dEPSCrop test.eps test.pdf` to produce a PDF file **test.pdf**.
4. I included my **test.tex** into a latex document using a line of code `\input{test.tex}`

After compiling with PDFLatex i get an error:

> test.tex:96:File 'test' not found, \put(0,0){\includegraphics{test}}

I am confused, because picture **test.pdf** is in the same folder as **test.tex**, but both are in a subfolder "pictures" of my root Latex folder.

Well here is the source code for **test.tex** that gnuplot produces. I hope it helps. The line that reports error is near the end of the file.

```
% GNUPLOT: LaTeX picture with Postscript
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Package color not loaded in conjunction with
      terminal option `colourtext'%
    }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
    }{Either use 'blacktext' in gnuplot or load the package
      color.sty in LaTeX.}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
    \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Package graphicx or graphics not loaded%
    }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
    }{The gnuplot epslatex terminal needs graphicx.sty or graphics.sty.}%
    \renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \@ifundefined{ifGPcolor}{%
    \newif\ifGPcolor
    \GPcolorfalse
  }{}%
  \@ifundefined{ifGPblacktext}{%
    \newif\ifGPblacktext
    \GPblacktexttrue
  }{}%
  % define a \g@addto@macro without @ in the name:
  \let\gplgaddtomacro\g@addto@macro
  % define empty templates for all commands taking text:
  \gdef\gplbacktext{}%
  \gdef\gplfronttext{}%
  \makeatother
  \ifGPblacktext
    % no textcolor at all
    \def\colorrgb#1{}%
    \def\colorgray#1{}%
  \else
    % gray or color?
    \ifGPcolor
      \def\colorrgb#1{\color[rgb]{#1}}%
      \def\colorgray#1{\color[gray]{#1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTw\endcsname{\color{white}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTb\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTa\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT0\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT1\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,1,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT2\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,0,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT3\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT4\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,1,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT5\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,1,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT6\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT7\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0.3,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT8\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}}%
    \else
      % gray
      \def\colorrgb#1{\color{black}}%
      \def\colorgray#1{\color[gray]{#1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTw\endcsname{\color{white}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTb\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTa\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT0\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT1\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT2\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT3\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT4\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT5\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT6\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT7\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT8\endcsname{\color{black}}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \setlength{\unitlength}{0.0500bp}%
  \begin{picture}(7200.00,5040.00)%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplbacktext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%
      \put(462,440){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{} 0}}%
      \put(462,1307){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{} 1}}%
      \put(462,2174){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{} 2}}%
      \put(462,3041){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{} 3}}%
      \put(462,3908){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{} 4}}%
      \put(462,4775){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{} 5}}%
      \put(594,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} 0}}%
      \put(1836,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} 2}}%
      \put(3078,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} 4}}%
      \put(4319,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} 6}}%
      \put(5561,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} 8}}%
      \put(6803,220){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} 10}}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplfronttext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%
      \put(5816,4602){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}f(x)}}%
    }%
    \gplbacktext
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics{test}}%
    \gplfronttext
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup
```

Comment: I would use pgfplots. It has a gnuplot command that can call scripts. Gnuplot then returns a .table file that is then plotted by pgfplots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research i found that **test.tex** produced by gnuplot holds a line `\put(0,0){\includegraphics{test}}%` which was suppose to include the **test.pdf** image.

I thought that if a command `\includegraphics{test}` is used in a **test.tex** destination of **test.pdf** would be relative to the destination of **test.tex** which is in a subfolder "pictures" of my root Latex folder.

But because i used a command `\input{./pictures/test}` inside my main Latex document, command `\includegraphics{test}` destinations inside it become relative to my root Latex folder.

Soo i could easily fix the problem modifying a line inside **test.tex** into a `\put(0,0)\includegraphics{./pictures/test}`.

Comment: Now i wonder, is there a Latex command like `\input` which doesn't change relative adressing inside inputted file?